# Where is the Full Circle magazine installed by the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

After clicking the buy button in the USC, I don't get anything. Browsing to a couple of issues in the USC, I see that I've already downloaded them, but there isn't anything showing up when I search.

Where did Ubuntu Software Center install the issues on my system?

Comment: What version of the Software Center are you using (`apt-cache policy software-center`)? Can you provide a link to the piece of software you are trying to buy/install from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the issue that you are inquiring about.  On my Ubuntu 12.10 setup, the PDF's of Full Circle Magazine are located in */opt/fullcircle/issues*.  I did not have to create the folder - it was automatically created when I installed an issue of Full Circle from the Ubuntu Software Center.